# Проблема с импортом Django

Tags: python, django, импорт

Нужно импортировать модели из соседнего файла. Пытался `from .models import Author, Tag, Quote`, но тогда ошибка что такого пакета нет. Поискал по просторам интернета и нашел якобы решение. Нужно добавить код:

```
from django.core.exceptions import MultipleObjectsReturned
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_quotes.settings')
django.setup()
```

Но мне это не помогло и выдает ошибку:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_quotes.settings'
```

[image: Дерево проекта]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте название приложения (app), из которого импортируете модели:

```
from quotes.models import Author, Tag, Quote
```

Тогда и при чтении кода будет сразу понятно, откуда эти модели, например, если у вас появятся новые приложения (app).

Иногда удобно импортировать вообще весь модуль моделей, чтобы не нужно было каждый раз помнить, что нужно добавить очередную модель в импорт:

```
from quotes import models as q_models
# это не самое удачное сокращенное название, оно тут для примера
```